# Type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to type 'number' on map function

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a function that takes an array of coordinates, takes the units out to make an array of them, and then takes out the biggest number out of said array. For example:

Turns this:
`[2.1, 3.4, 1.7, 5.2, 4.4]`

To this:
`[2, 3, 1, 5, 4]`

To return 5

My code looks like this:

```
const getLastPage = (items: OrderItemType[]) => {
    let pagesArray = items.map((orderItem) => {
        const valueStringArray = orderItem.value.toString().split('.');
        const pageValue = parseInt(valueStringArray[0]);
        if (!isNaN(pageValue)) return pageValue;
    });
    return Math.max.apply(Math, pagesArray);
}
```

However, my code throws the following error on my `return`

`Type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.`

I tried to resolve it using a non-null asertion on my `pagesArray` variable, however, that throws me a syntax error, I don't know why.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `if (!isNaN(pageValue)) return pageValue;` The opposite of this case is that you return undefined, and Math.max doesn't expect undefined. What do you want to happen with those undefined values?

Comment: @NicholasTower Just omit them entirely, don't add them to the array

Comment: Why not just return `-Infinity`? Or you could filter the `undefined` out with a type predicate...

Comment: Additional recommendation, you can use `Math.floor` instead of string operations.

Answer (score 0):

`.map` always returns an array of the exact same length as the original, so if you want to filter out the undefineds you will need to call `.filter` afterwards, with a type guard function:

```
let pagesArray = items.map((orderItem) => {
  const valueStringArray = orderItem.value.toString().split('.');
  const pageValue = parseInt(valueStringArray[0]);
  if (!isNaN(pageValue)) return pageValue;
}).filter((pageValue: number | undefined): page is number => pageValue !== undefined);
```

Alternatively, you could construct the array using something other than map, so that you can selectively decide whether to add to the array or not. A for loop for example:

```
let pagesArray: number[] = []
for (let orderItem of items) {
  const valueStringArray = orderItem.value.toString().split('.');
  const pageValue = parseInt(valueStringArray[0]);
  if (!isNaN(pageValue)) pagesArray.push(pageValue);
}
```